# Combine variant flags in tailwindcss e.g. even:bg-color-black even:dark:bg-color-white

Tags: tailwind-css

I've made a table in zebra style using tailwindcss. But now that I need to add dark mode support it's not applying the dark mode color and keeps the light mode color altough all other colors do change as expected.

I've made a `even:bg-color` which works and a `even:dark:bg-color` which doesnt.

```html
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items"
    class="even:bg-stone-light even:dark:bg-slate-darker h-10">
    <td class="w-10 pl-2">{{name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This results in a view like here where the (bright variant is correct):

[image: Differences in variants]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dark:` should go [first](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#stacking-with-other-variants)

> The dark variant can be combined with both responsive variants and state variants (like hover and focus):
> The responsive variant needs to come first, then dark, then the state variant for this to work.

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rCYiCems14) - toggle `dark` class at the top